# How open file stored in app specific storage in external app android?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, storage

I have stored files like pdf and ppt in app-specific storage. And now I want to open these files on an external app.

When I tried to open the file using the Intent I am getting an exception: exposed beyond app through ClipData.Item.getUri()

How can I do that?

Thanks In advance:)

Comment: FileProvider...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I am not able to see the code through which you are trying to open the file from external app, all i can suggest is please save your app specific data in a shared storage of external directories as suggested by Android docs.

I would recommend this [Save data to app specific location](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/app-specific)

and [Save data to shared storage](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared)